# Association without join table in Mongoid

Tags: mongoid

In our Mongo database we have two collections: `roles` and `policies`.

A role can have multiple policies and in a normal relational database we'd have a join table to connect these two collections together. However this is an existing database and is used with a custom ORM in a different service, and we'd like to use Mongoid in this new service without changing the schema of the database.

A typical example of the documents:

Role:

```
{
  _id: ObjectId('589da845f3310b61ba0a78e0'),
  name: 'ADMIN',
  policy_ids: [
    {
      policy_id: '17b20fdb-c752-4215-8f7c-7fa4c9521168'
    }
  ]
}
```

Policy:

```
{
  _id: ObjectId('58d3f9dba6fca01bce8fc618'),
  actions: {...}
}
```

In our `role` model using: `has_many :policies` won't work because it expects to use a join table to find these associated documents.

We can define the field with: `field :policy_ids, type: Array, default: []` but that doesn't make it an association... so the only way to access the data is to add a custom method like:

```
def policies
  Policy.in([id: policy_ids.map { |p| p['policy_id'] }])
end
```

But that feels a bit nasty and doesn't help when updating records, etc...

Is there a way to get Mongoid to see these policies as associated without having to do custom logic?